# kendoDatePicker fails on IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer-9, kendo-ui, internet-explorer-10

The following test page runs OK on IE9 but throws a jQuery exception in IE 10. Not really a question but I thought I should share my experience.

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="styles/LPStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#datePicker").kendoDatePicker();
        });
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="datePicker" value="10/10/2011" style="width:150px;" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm seeing this problem, but only when my web-application is deployed onto a linux server (Redhat, Java 6_43, Tomcat5.5). If it's on a windows machine, with everything else the same, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

What version of jQuery are you using?

The latest version of Kendo ( 2013 Q1 ) upgraded to jQuery 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo UI date picker is not working in below scenarios 
Browser Mode: IE 10 Document Mode: IE5 Quirks mode

You can force the browser document mode to any other document mode.

OR

Try the below code

```
 try{
        $("#datePicker").kendoDatePicker();
    }
 catch(err){}
```